Remove SRCSET for new images and past pages, and then delete all unused duplicate images created by wordpress and theme
I am faced with a major issue regarding the duplication of images in my uploads folder by both Wordpress and my theme, upwards of 10 different variants, as such my directory has ballooned to over 12 GB. Crazy! I have been searching endlessly for a solution and have come across a great deal of knowledge but no clear solution to do all of the following. I did find a solution on here to disable the srcset, but it will then only do it for new uploads. I have tried Media Cleaner, EWWWW Image Optimizer but its not working. I simply want to do the following:

Disable this Srcset setting but then also remove this from all past pages. So run something that will then remove this from all existing pages so there is just one image been called for in the code
Once the srcset images are then unattached (no longer associated with the code), run something to delete it

I tried several different plugins such as meow media cleaner, bulk optimizer, and EWWW image optimizer but its only marginally reducing current images. Its not dealing with the removal of Srcset from all current pages and then offering a solution to delete them once removed from the code in the source. In a nutshell I just want to use one image and for all these duplicates to be removed and safely deleted.
